# Disabling a button from another controller in JavaFXML

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder, netbeans-platform

I am working on a netbeansIDE javaFXML project and when i login with username and password to a second screen i want the second screens button be disabled. I have tried to disable the button in the other controller like this by using Getter but nothing happens when i am logged in. 
I really hope something can help, i tried to search help and i found some, and tried but ended with this and now i am stuck.

Here is my code:

```
{@FXML
private void handleLogin(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {

    String username = txtUsername.getText();
    String password = txtPassword.getText();

    Button pressed_button = (Button) event.getSource();

    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
    loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("Screen3_Scada.fxml"));
    loader.load();
     if(pressed_button==btnscadalogin){
        if (loginLoad.validateSCADA(username, password)) {

            try {
                AnchorPane pane = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Screen3_Scada.fxml"));
                 RootPane.getChildren().setAll(pane);

                 Screen3_Scada_Controller getbtnPLC = loader.getController();
                 getbtnPLC.getBtngotoPLC().setDisable(true);

             }catch (IOException ex) {
                System.err.println("Error in method GotoScreen2 class FXML_Screen1_loginController");
             }

        }else{
            System.err.println("Error, wrong username or password");
        }


    }
}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're loading the scene twice:

```
loader.load();
...
AnchorPane pane = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Screen3_Scada.fxml"));
```

`getbtnPLC` is not the controller instance that is created when you load the scene you add to the existing one.

You should use the loaded result that is the result of the `loader.load();` call:

```
if (pressed_button == btnscadalogin) {
    if (loginLoad.validateSCADA(username, password)) {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("Screen3_Scada.fxml"));

        try {
            AnchorPane pane = loader.load();
            RootPane.getChildren().setAll(pane);

            Screen3_Scada_Controller getbtnPLC = loader.getController();
            getbtnPLC.getBtngotoPLC().setDisable(true);

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.err.println("Error in method GotoScreen2 class FXML_Screen1_loginController");
        }
   }
```

I do recommend using different methods for handling `ActionEvent`s from different sources. This is usually the better alternative than checking which one of multiple nodes is the source of the event.